# Increase font size of SQL query box

Tags: phpmyadmin

The font-size of the `textarea` that accepts SQL queries on my phpMyAdmin installation is too small. One workaround I found is to increase the minimum font size in Chrome, but it's breaking the look of other websites.

How can the font size be increased?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Find your phpMyAdmin directory.

```
   cd themes
```

You may see more than one theme, and you want to make changes in the theme you are using -- phpMyAdmin lets you choose your theme. I use the original theme, so I made changes there.

Go to the css directory of the theme

```
   cd original/css /* or your preferred theme */
```

Use a text editor like nano to modify theme_right.css.php

```
   nano theme_right.css.php
```

Search for 2 style definitions

```
   .CodeMirror pre
   .CodeMirror textarea
```

Both will show "font-size: inherit" or font-size:inherit!important

Change to

```
    font-size: 16px; /* or whatever you prefer */
```

Save and reload phpMyAdmin
Note that you may need to clear your browser cache for these changes to appear.

Comment: This worked for me. Was looking for it to increase the size of my SQL font. Excellent suggestion; I think the other one may be for a different version of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: In case of phpMyAdmin 4.5.4.1 and Ubuntu 16 I had to add font-size: 16px; into .CodeMirror { ... } in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/css/codemirror.css.php

Comment: Thanks @Mike - same is true for 4.9.7deb1 on Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 17):

I Had the same problem using phpMyAdmin with xampp.

to fix, go to

```
xampp > phpMyAdmin > themes > pmahomme > css
```

open the following file with your text editor

```
codemirror.css.php
```

and add the following line to the very bottom of the file

```
.CodeMirror pre {font-size:1.4em;}
```

Now save the file and that should do it!

(if phpMyAdmin is using a different theme to pmahomme then just add that line

of code to every codemirror.css.php file you can find!

Comment: I’ve been looking for this for a long time. Why isn’t there a setting in the application itself? I have also included the line number in my own setup, so I now have something like this: `div.CodeMirror pre,
div.CodeMirror-linenumber {
 font-size: 2rem;
}`. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Go to the css directory of the theme

cd /var/www/html/myadmin11/themes/original/css

Then 
  vi  theme_right.css.php

find the "textarea#sqlquery" and change it

```
 textarea#sqlquery {
 font-size:2em;  /* add this line to what font size you want */
 width: 80%;
 height: 300%;
 }
```

Comment: what is em? *some random characters to post comment*

Answer (score 2):

If you are using "phpmyadmin 4.8.1" then go to `xampp\phpMyAdmin\js\vendor\codemirror\lib`,
open codemirror.css,
find `font-size: inherit;` and replace it with `font-size: 2em;`

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Home button under phpmyadmin in left:

[image]

Then you can change theme and font size.

Comment: The only one solution which worked for me and the easyest and fastest one! Should be marked as the principal solution!

Answer (score 0):

on phpmyadmin 4.6 found the ".Codemirror pre" in :

themes/theThemeUsed/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css

Answer (score 0):

On phpmyadmin 4.9.5 just change the ".Codemirror" in:

> \phpMyAdmin\js\vendor\codemirror\lib\codemirror.css

add:

```
font-size: 1.5em;  /* add this line to what font size you want */
```

Also change the file: "common.css.php" in:

> \phpMyAdmin\themes\your_theme\css\common.css.php

in that file search for and add:

```
    textarea,
    tt,
    pre,
    code {
    font-family: <?php echo $GLOBALS['cfg']['FontFamilyFixed']; ?>;
    font-size: 1.5em; /* add this line to what font size you want */
    }
```

And that should do it!

With this you will see a better size font on query textarea when edit and to view the query when you are not editing.