# How do I change phpmyadmin font size for sql query box?

Tags: php, css, phpmyadmin, themes

I'm using phpmyadmin 5.5.42

If i click on the SQL tab, or if i click on a database > table name and look at the SQL query it is written in a courier-like font at a far smaller size than the surrounding text. Similarly if I click edit inline, the font size is very small.

I'm trying to make a course using screenshots etc, so making the SQL query as large as possible is really important. I know how to make the font as a whole bigger, either through my browser or in phpmyadmin, but that doesn't help as the problem is the relative size of the SQL text and the surrounding text.

I've found this: [Increase font size of SQL query box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816991/increase-font-size-of-sql-query-box)

I don't have a theme_right.css.php in my phpmyadmin > themes > originals > css folder. The likeliest candidate is common.css.php but changing stuff here has had no effect at all. There is also printview.css and navigation.css.php which i haven't tried but don't seem likely.

My text editor suggests my page is actually using phpmyadmin > phpmyadmin.css.php but this has no CSS in it, just a load of php pulling in other files and presumably talking to the database.

Does anyone know how to modify the appearance of SQL query in the Browse and SQL tabs in phpmyadmin 5.5.42?

Thanks
Emma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try add font-size for

```
.CodeMirror pre
.CodeMirror textarea
```

directly in phpmyadmin.css.php, after "?>"

Comment: Surprisingly, there is no ?> in this file, despite the file opening with <php. Anyway, I added the closing statement and then tried to set the font size but no joy. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Actually I take it back - this has worked when editing the SQL (thank you!!). Is there a way to make it work even when the SQL is not selected, but just displayed?

Comment: Add font-size for 
`#result_query .inner_sql` too

Answer (score 3):

On the left pane of phpMyAdmin, click the tiny 'Home' icon provided at the top. 
Then increase the percentage of font size in 'Appearance Settings' section.